# C# datetime array

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

I have two arrays, array1 has datetime data count by minute from 8am to 2pm and array2 has datetime data count by hour from same date 8am to 1pm.

I want to output the index number of two array that has same datetime.hour. and it should matchup the last available index number of array2 for all of the datetime data from array1 that later than array2.

for example if I have two datetime array like this:

```
DateTime[] dateTimes1 = new DateTime[]
        {

            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 15, 0),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 30, 1),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 45, 2),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 15, 3),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 30, 4),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 45, 5),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 15, 6),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 30, 7),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 45, 8),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 15, 9),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 30, 10),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 45, 11),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 15, 12),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 30, 13),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 45, 14),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 15, 15),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 30, 16),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 45, 17),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 15, 18),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 30, 19),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 45, 20),
        };

        DateTime[] dateTimes2 = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 0, 0),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 0, 1),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 0, 2),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 0, 3),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 0, 4),
            new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 0, 5),
        };
```

it should gives me the output:

0, 0
1, 0
2, 0
3, 1
4, 1
5, 1
6, 2
7, 2
8, 2
9, 3
10, 3
11, 3
12, 4
13, 4
14, 4
15, 5
16, 5
17, 5
18, 5
19, 5
20, 5

This is what I have tried:

```
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (i < dateTimes1.Length && j < dateTimes2.Length)
            {     
                if (dateTimes1[i].Date == dateTimes2[j].Date && dateTimes1[i].Hour == dateTimes2[j].Hour)
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                    list2.Add(j);
                    i++;
                }
                else if (dateTimes1[i] < dateTimes2[j])
                {
                    i++;
                }
                else if (dateTimes1[i] > dateTimes2[j])
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(list[k] + " , " + list2[k];
            }
```

but it won't output the index number after 1pm.

Comment: Nice beginner exercise. What did you try? Or do you think we are a "write my code for free" service? We generally want people to have a programming problem based on code. Not have them dump their homework on us, so they never learn programming.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  A loop would be simple but somewhat inefficient - try that and see if you can;t come up with a more efficient method later.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "datetime data count" nor "last available counter of array2". The elements in the arrays aren't counters, they're just `DateTime` values. Please clarify. If you're using the `Second` part of the `DateTime` as a counter, I *strongly* recommend that you stop doing so, right now.

Comment: I have added my code

Comment: Your two lists are not the same length my friend. So you need your first loop and then, inside it, you need to loop the other list. This way, for each entry in loop 1 you will compare it against all entries in inner loop 2. Inside the inner loop you do the comparison and if they match, add them to the lists.

Answer (score 2):

Your two lists are not the same **length**. In your **while** statement you are trying to iterate two different length lists at the same time.

If I understand your requirements properly you should be doing something like this by using an **inner** loop:

```
DateTime[] dateTimes1 = new DateTime[]
    {

        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 15, 0),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 30, 1),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 45, 2),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 15, 3),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 30, 4),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 45, 5),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 15, 6),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 30, 7),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 45, 8),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 15, 9),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 30, 10),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 45, 11),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 15, 12),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 30, 13),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 45, 14),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 15, 15),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 30, 16),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 45, 17),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 15, 18),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 30, 19),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 14, 45, 20),
    };

    DateTime[] dateTimes2 = new DateTime[]
    {
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 8, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 9, 0, 1),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 10, 0, 2),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 11, 0, 3),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 12, 0, 4),
        new DateTime(2010, 10, 1, 13, 0, 5),
    };

    int i = 0;
    while (i < dateTimes1.Length)
    {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < dateTimes2.Length))
        {
            if (dateTimes1[i].Date == dateTimes2[j].Date && dateTimes1[i].Hour == dateTimes2[j].Hour)
            {
                list.Add(i);
                list2.Add(j);
                i++;
            }
            else if (dateTimes1[i] < dateTimes2[j])
            {
                i++;
            }
            else if (dateTimes1[i] > dateTimes2[j])
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < list.Count; k++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[k] + " , " + list2[k];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty basic method using `Array.FindIndex` and `foreach`:

EDIT: Updated this answer to handle the "*matchup the last available index number of array2 for all of the datetime data from array1 that later than array2.*" issue.

```
foreach (DateTime dt in dateTimes1)
{   
    int currentHour = dt.Hour;
    int lastHour = dateTimes2[dateTimes2.GetUpperBound(0)].Hour; //GetUpperBound(0) is the last index

    int dt1index = Array.FindIndex(dateTimes1, a => a == dt); //get the index of the current item in dateTimes1
    int dt2index = Array.FindIndex(dateTimes2, x => x.Hour == currentHour); //get the index of the item in dateTimes2 matching dateTimes1 hour field        

    if (currentHour > lastHour)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dt1index, dateTimes2.GetUpperBound(0));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dt1index, dt2index);
    }             

}
```

This simply looks at each of the values in `dateTimes1` and `dateTimes2` and returns the first match it finds (very similar to your loop).

To determine `dt1index`, we look through `dateTimes1` and return the first match where `a => a == dt` (a is just the predicate, representing the "current" value in `dateTimes1` - think of `i = 0,1,2,etc` in a regular loop ).

Similarly, to determine `dt2index`, we look for the first match on `x => x.Hour == dt.Hour` -- that is, where the "current" `dt`'s hour field matches the hour field in `dateTimes2`.

In both cases, the first match is returned - if no matches are found, `-1` is returned.

When we go to write to the console, we check if `currentHour` is greater than the last hour in `dateTimes2` if so, we just write the current index of `dateTimes1` and the last index of `dateTimes2`. Otherwise, we write the current index of `dateTimes1` and the index where the hour matches on `dateTimes2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq:

```
var hour = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);
var dt2MaxValue = dateTimes2.Max();
for (int i = 0; i < dateTimes1.Length; i++)
{
    var output = string.Format("{0}, {1}",
        i,
        dateTimes2
           .Select((o, index) => new { index = index, value = o })
           .Where(dt2 => (dateTimes1[i] - dt2.value) < hour 
                           || dt2.value == dt2MaxValue)
           .Select(dt2 => dt2.index)
           .FirstOrDefault());
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

What the above Linq statement does:

- The first `Select` uses that method's overload which also passes the index of the item. This simply allows that info to cascade through. It uses an anonymous object with both index and the collection item being the `index` and `value`  properties, respectively.
- The `Where` clause queries the collection of these anonymous objects and compares their `value` with `dateTime1[i]`. It gets the one where `value` is less than `dateTime1[i]` but not by more than 1 hour, *OR* if it is the maximum `value` in the whole collection.
- The second `Select` simply gets the indexes of the items that `Where` filtered through.
- And `FirstOrDefault` returns just that (ie, the first or default, which is the index of the item selected or 0 if no item was selected).